# After deploy my app.yaml is not update (node js, app engine standard)

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want to deploy a app.yaml conf but when it's deploy, it's not my config but a default config I guess.

here my app.yaml

```
service: api-collaborator-std
runtime: nodejs8
env: standard
instance_class: F2

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: auto

automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 1
  min_instances: 0
  max_instances: 1
```

and when it's deploy it's look like this

```
runtime: nodejs8
env: standard
instance_class: F2
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
  - url: .*
    script: auto
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: automatic
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: automatic
  max_pending_latency: automatic
  max_instances: 1
network: {}
```

Comment: Do you have a default service in your project?

Comment: Yes, but when I put 0 value, the property disappear but it works. Because with this config I was 1 instance after deploy, but today it scale to 0, so 0 instance. And I'm right before in manual scaling with instances:1 it was always 1 instance so I paid for it although I don't use it? But now with scale to 0, instance: 0 I will pay nothing ?